# How to create ConfigurationList in SharePoint site for EventReceiver?

Tags: custom-list, event-receivers, configuration

I want to create ConfigurationList which should store/display information like, 
with 2 columns(Title & Value).

For Example:

ContentTypes:  101;107

Event Types:   Add;Update;Delete

Location:      http.://./Lists/MyTempList1;http.://./Lists/TaskList

Value: *************

How should I create this & where to write all the stuff ?
It should be in the ContentType or using EventReceiver ?

Answer (score 0):

For clarification....

is the question about:

1. how to create a list?
2. how to automatically put data( Content Types, Event Types, Location and Value) into the list?

Comment: Yes theodor.johannesen. How to create it & how to automatically put data ?

Comment: Hi Shahid. Creation of a list, with the right columns is a trivial process. That you can "google". Here is one example... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eov27nKnImo

Relating to gathering the table metadata, can be solved programatically, by tracercing all SPFarm --> SPSite --> SPWeb --> SPList object, and checking on content types, event receivers etc.
The code could be executed within a so called "SharePoint Feature", or in a sharepoint consol application.